# Probability to get from point A to point B.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the photo each dot is a city and each blue segment a road. Each road is blocked with probability 1/3 and free with probability 2/3 (independence among all roads). What is the probability that it is possible to travel from city A to city B by only taking free roads.

[image]

My attempt:
I think there are 3 different ways of arriving at B from A.
And there are 14 different ways in total of placing the probabilities, I mean like from A to first red dot that is on the top, you have two probabilities to choose from. 
And so one. So choosing the top route, you get: 2+2+2=6 ways of choosing till the next intersection, and then 2*2=4 ways to B. And choosing the bottom route, you get 2*2=4 ways till the intersection and then it is the same 4 ways till B. That is why I said 6+4+4=14 ways of choosing the probability from A to B. But how do I use the probability 1/3 and 2/3?

Can anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be the node of degree $4$, $D$ the node of degree $3$. We can replace the double edge $DC$ by a single edge that has a different probability of being blocked: $DC$ is blocked only if both edges are blocked, hence blocked with $\frac19$ and free with $\frac 89$.

Hence the "northern route" from $A$ to $C$ is free with probability $\frac23\cdot \frac89=\frac{16}{27}$ and blocked with $\frac{11}{27}$.
The "southern route" from $A$ to $C$ is free with $\frac23\cdot \frac23=\frac49$ and blocked with $\frac59$.
The route $A$ to $C$ is totally blocked only if both these routes are (independently!) blocked, i.e., blocked with $\frac{11}{27}\cdot\frac59=\frac{55}{243}$ and free with $\frac{188}{243}$. Since we must pass through $C$ to get to $B$ and there are two edges between $C$ and $B$ that both must be free, the overall success probability is
$$ \frac{188}{243}\cdot \frac23\cdot \frac23=\frac{752}{2187}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let S be the event that the southern route is free and N the event that the northern route is free.

Then $\displaystyle P(S\cup N)=P(S)+P(N)-P(S\cap N)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\cdot\left(1-\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)^2\right)-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5\cdot\left(1-\big(\frac{1}{3}\big)^2\right)$

$\hspace{.6 in}=\displaystyle\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\left[\frac{2}{3}+\frac{8}{9}-\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{8}{9}\right]=\frac{752}{2187}$